# find an button and assign an id via jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page that includes two forms... both within a `<DL>`

```
<dl>
<form action="" method="POST" style="display:inline-block;">
    <dl><dt></dt><dd><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Create TEST" style="width: 15em;"></dd></dl>
</form>
<form action="" method="POST" style="display:inline-block;">
    <dl><dt></dt><dd><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Create TEST2" style="width: 15em;"></dd></dl>
</form>    
</dl>
```

I need to find both buttons and assign ids to them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//find the two create buttons and assign ids
$('body FORM:contains("Create TEST")').contents().each(function () {
var exp = /Create TEST/;        
if (this.nodeValue && exp.test(this.nodeValue)) {                      
    var $createoutrule = this;
    $createoutrule.attr('id',"id123");
    return 
}; 
});
```

But it's not working... can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm going to google .contents() to make sure I understand how / what it should be returning...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:contains` looks for *textual* content.

Your selector can be much simpler:

```
$('input[type=submit][value^="Create TEST"]')...
```

...which means "an `input` with `type` `"submit"` whose value attribute *starts with* `"Create TEST"`".

To add `id` values to them (note that they must be two *different* `id` values, because `id`s **must** be unique on the page), then:

```
$('input[type=submit][value^="Create TEST"]').each(function(index) {
    this.id = "id" + index; // Will be "id0" then "id1"
});
```

Of course, as you already have the buttons using the above code, you may not need to assign `id` values to them anymore, you can just do whatever you were going to do with them later using `id`s right away in the code above. But if your use-case requires `id`s, the above'll do it.

---

If those values are just placeholders, the same general principal applies: If the both *start with* the same text, you can use the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) above; if not, there's also the [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), the [attribute-contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), ...

Answer (score 0):

You can get all submit type button on forms using    $( " :submit ").functionname()

Comment: means you can set attribute also there like this: $( ":submit" ).addClass( "marked" );

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$('input[type="submit"]').each(function () {
          var exp = /Create TEST/;   

           if (exp.test(this.value)) {                      

                     $(this).attr('id',"id123");//put diffrent id because id should be unique
                     return ;
           }; 
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tSXD5/)**